# \SIrange[tophrase=dash] fails to render an en-dash

Tags: siunitx

When using `\SIrange[tophrase=dash]` to specify a range of numbers with units, the range phrase is literally specified as `dash`.

The following MWE yields `10 mdash20 m` as an output.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per=slash, load=abbr}

\begin{document}

\SIrange[tophrase=dash]{10}{20}{\metre}

\end{document}
```

Whats going on here? Where should I be looking?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use it with `range-phrase={--}`. But it can be confused with a subtraction operation so better to use `to` instead to specify a range:

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per=slash, load=abbr}

\begin{document}

\SIrange[range-phrase={--}]{10}{20}{\metre}

\SIrange[range-phrase={~to~}]{10}{20}{\metre}

% for the ancient version 1, use tophrase
% \SIrange[tophrase={~to~}]{10}{20}{\metre}

\end{document}
```

Comment: My apologies for taking so long to reply. Your answer works well. Thanks! What I still don't get is why the method suggested in the `siunitx` documentation fails to work.

Comment: @Ricardo: Don't know. Perhaps you have an old version of the documentation?

Comment: That was it. I had a very old version of the documentation.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: With the version 2 of siunit package, the code will turn something like into \SIrange[range-phrase=--]{10}{20}{\metre}